# arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found

Tags: gcc, arm

I've been trying to run OP-TEE on IMX6Q following this tutorial http://mrvan.github.io/optee-imx6q-sabresd . when I get to the part OPTEE XTEST and run the command make ARCH=arm I get the error **make[1]: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found** !

So I figured out that I need to install it but I couldn't find a proper tutorial ! can you help me please that would be awesome.

PS: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 !

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: thank you for your response but I tried this already and it asked me to download another 3 packages and so on ! and nothing is installed !